# Browsers report invalid value for `grid-template-areas`, but validator says it's correct

Tags: css, css-grid

My css is as follows:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-areas: "a0 b0 c0 d0 e0 f0 b0" "g1 g1 g1 g1 g1 . ." "i2 i2 i2 i2 . . ." "j3 j3 j3 . k3 k3 k3" "l4 l4 m4 m4 . . ." "a5 b5 c5 n5 n5 o5 o5" ". . . d6 e6 f6 .";
```

Let me lay out the grid so it's easier to view:

```
"a0 b0 c0 d0 e0 f0 b0"
"g1 g1 g1 g1 g1 . ."
"i2 i2 i2 i2 . . ."
"j3 j3 j3 . k3 k3 k3"
"l4 l4 m4 m4 . . ."
"a5 b5 c5 n5 n5 o5 o5"
". . . d6 e6 f6 ."
```

I used this grid validator, which reports it's valid: https://github.com/evrom/grid-validator

- has 7 rows
- is rectangular
- has 7 columns per row
- All areas are contiguous and rectangular

Why does the browser not parse it and say `Invalid value`?

**Browsers I tried:** Chrome, Firefox

Comment: Does it work? Chrome's dev tools sometimes gets confused about what's OK in CSS, but Chrome itself understands the same CSS fine.

Comment: @Alohci Unfortunately, no, the grid isn't applied at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking very closely, the first row contains `b0` twice.

Too bad the validator doesn't catch this!